# 2D Collision Detection methods not getting called

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I know this question has been asked before, but I could not find an answer anywhere so please do not mark this as a duplicate.

I am trying to make a 2D game in Unity in which I need to detect bullets hitting enemies.

I have a Box Collider 2D and a Rigidbody 2D on both the enemy prefab and the bullet prefab.

First off I tried doing it without the 'Is Trigger' box checked.

This is the code I was using :

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D)
{
    Debug.Log("Detected !");
}
```

No success.

Next I tried putting a check in the 'Is Triggered' box, and used this code :

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(other: Collider2D)
{
    Debug.Log("Detected !");
}
```

Once again, no success...

The components I have on both objects are 'Box Collider 2D'.

Neither of the methods I tried returned any error messages, the functions just didn't get called.

If anyone please has an idea what's going on, please let me know ASAP – I cannot continue working on my game until this works :/

Is this a bug with Unity ?  Should I report it ?

Also, here is a screenshot of the inspector on one of the objects :
[image: Screenshot]

Cheers to anyone who can answer all my questions !  Sorry if I didn't format my post right, I'm kinda new to the forum...

Fjpackard.

Comment: I think you have attached 3d-physics components to your gameObjects! check if they are 2d! and update the question.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case :/  The components are 'Box Collider 2D'.  Will update question.

Comment: Check that you are not trying to detect collisions between 2D colliders (colliders found under `Physics 2D` tab of Add Component) and 3D colliders (colliders found under `Physics` tab of Add Component). They are not colliding with each other at all.

Comment: I just updated the question, they are both 'Box Collider 2D'.

Comment: @Fjpackard Check out the collision action matrix on this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html - since your bullets move, your bullets are going to need Rigidbody2D components.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add a [Rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) to both enemy and bullet prefabs (deactivating Gravity).

With this modification in both prefabs it must work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer – Do I add a Rigidbody2D to both the objects as well as the Box Collider 2D, or delete the Box Collider 2D first ?

Comment: Both. You have to add the Box Collider 2D and the Rigidbody2D. Test it and ask me for any doubt.

Comment: Have you turn off `isKinematic`?

Comment: It was off by default.

Comment: are you using `OnCollisionEnter2D` or `OnTriggerEnter2D`?

Comment: I'm currently using 'OnTriggerEnter2D'.

Comment: Test it using `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead.

Comment: I tested it – still the function did not trigger, but something happened this time !  When the bullet hit the enemies, they moved, and the bullets kind of ricocheted.

Comment: Try this time to set `Collision Detection` to Continuous and turn on `isKinematic`. If this does not works when I have time I'll post an example!

Comment: BTW. have you attached the code to the bullet or the enemy or some other GameObject?

Comment: Also If you can post a capture of your inspector for the object would be great.

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: Try turning on `is Tigger` in the Box Collider parameters.

Comment: I'm reading some documentation and as far as I have read _"isKinematic also disables collisions and triggers when used in 2D"_ so finally try again to turn off `isKinematic` please, but mantaining `is Tigger` on. Sorry if I'm confusing you a little bit with this all modifications.

Comment: I will try it.  No, don't worry, thanks so much for all the help !  Everyone one these forums is so kind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70375/discussion-between-fjpackard-and-unai).

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured it out...

I was actually using an old version of Unity – it was as simple as that !

Thanks everyone who helped.

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Comment: I _think_ it was Unity 4.5.5f1.